# how to remove vendor name from crosstool-ng toolchain name

Tags: linux

How do I configure crosstool-ng to drop the vendor name from the generated toolchain name.

For example to create an arm cross toolchain without specifying a vendor part would result in the following naming output

> arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++

If I had supplied a vendor for instance "linaro" then I would have an output such as

> arm-linaro-linux-gnueabihf-g++

What I want is to make the crosstool-ng to output the name as follows

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

I am aware that you can use the "Tuple's sed transform" and the "Tuple's alias" these facilities from menuconfig but these only create symbolic links to the arm-unknown-gnueabihf-g++ etc.

I have a toolchain that came with a board I am playing with and these toolchain have the vendor's part omitted. So my question "How do they do that?"

Comment: since `arm` on its own is not very well defined, i think that adding more information, like the vendor, is rather favourable.

Comment: umlaute thanks for your reply

Comment: i wish I could add 10 stars to this

Comment: for me the situation is compiling QT for raspberry pi stretch, which now has libaries in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf instead of /usr/lib/arm-raspbian-linux-gnueabihf which is determined by -dumpmachine in the configuration code

Comment: machineTuple = $$eval($${currentConfig}.tests.machineTuple.tuple)
            !isEmpty(machineTuple): \
                pkgConfigLibdir = "$$pkgConfigLibdir:$$sysroot/usr/lib/$$machineTuple/pkgconfig"

Answer (score 4):

Even if the documentation states that:

> CT_TARGET_VENDOR: [...] It can be set to empty, to remove the vendor string from the target tuple.

(see http://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/configuration/ )

The current behavior is to fall back to 'unknown' if no value for CT_TARGET_VENDOR is given.

This situation was discussed within the crosstool-ng mailing list back in 2011 and there was a patch provided with a solution which may help you.

The idea of the patch was to:

> [...] supplies a fake vendor and 
>   then strips it out afterwards.

within scripts/functions of the crosstool-ng source.

See: https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2011-10/msg00047.html

```
diff -r a31d097e28cd -r 5b1330e7264a scripts/functions
--- a/scripts/functions Wed Oct 19 15:27:32 2011 +1300
+++ b/scripts/functions Wed Oct 19 16:23:36 2011 +1300
@@ -944,6 +944,20 @@
     fi
 }

+# Computes the target tuple from the configuration and the supplied
+# vendor string
+CT_BuildOneTargetTuple() {
+    local vendor="${1}"
+    local target
+
+    target="${CT_TARGET_ARCH}"
+    target="${target}${vendor:+-${vendor}}"
+    target="${target}${CT_TARGET_KERNEL:+-${CT_TARGET_KERNEL}}"
+    target="${target}${CT_TARGET_SYS:+-${CT_TARGET_SYS}}"
+
+    echo "${target}"
+}
+
 # Compute the target tuple from what is provided by the user
 # Usage: CT_DoBuildTargetTuple
 # In fact this function takes the environment variables to build the target
@@ -994,10 +1008,7 @@
     CT_DoKernelTupleValues

     # Finish the target tuple construction
-    CT_TARGET="${CT_TARGET_ARCH}"
-    CT_TARGET="${CT_TARGET}${CT_TARGET_VENDOR:+-${CT_TARGET_VENDOR}}"
-    CT_TARGET="${CT_TARGET}${CT_TARGET_KERNEL:+-${CT_TARGET_KERNEL}}"
-    CT_TARGET="${CT_TARGET}${CT_TARGET_SYS:+-${CT_TARGET_SYS}}"
+    CT_TARGET=$(CT_BuildOneTargetTuple "${CT_TARGET_VENDOR}")

     # Sanity checks
     __sed_alias=""
@@ -1012,7 +1023,14 @@
     esac

     # Canonicalise it
-    CT_TARGET=$(CT_DoConfigSub "${CT_TARGET}")
+    if [ -n "${CT_TARGET_VENDOR}" ]; then
+        CT_TARGET=$(CT_DoConfigSub "${CT_TARGET}")
+    else
+        # Canonicalise with a fake vendor string then strip it out
+        local target=$(CT_BuildOneTargetTuple "CT_INVALID")
+        CT_TARGET=$(CT_DoConfigSub "${target}" |sed -r -s s:CT_INVALID-::)
+    fi
+
     # Prepare the target CFLAGS
     CT_ARCH_TARGET_CFLAGS="${CT_ARCH_TARGET_CFLAGS} ${CT_ARCH_ENDIAN_CFLAG}"
     CT_ARCH_TARGET_CFLAGS="${CT_ARCH_TARGET_CFLAGS} ${CT_ARCH_ARCH_CFLAG}"
```